# Cannot resume from suspend ubuntu 16.04 Gnome

Tags: gnome, 16.04, suspend, resume

I have laptop lenovo g40-45 with ubuntu 16.04 Gnome installed.

The problem is that after suspend, i just got blank screen and cannot do anything but force-shutdown from power button.

I had ubuntu 14.04 unity installed before, it suspends and resumed perfectly.

My question: is it hardware problem or a gnome problem?

Comment: We *could* try a workaround, with a keyboard  shortcut. Would that interest you? Would save you a restart if it works.

Comment: From a terminal, what happens if you run `sudo pm-suspend` ?  Does it suspend and resume properly?

Comment: @XToro, i got this "sudo: pm-suspend: command not found"

Comment: Please enter this in terminal : `sudo apt-get install pm-utils` then restart your computer and try again.

Comment: Did you solved this? I suffer something similar too

Comment: Sorry, i didn't find it.
FYI : I installed gnome because it has better appearance than unity.
But now i'm using unity with custom appearance (using ubuntu tweak tool), so it has better appearance than gnome, and also there's another bug i found in gnome that makes me move to unity..

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu and ATI have collaborated to develop new open source graphics drivers to replace *fglrx* which existed on 14.04.

It is not a hardware problem since you can perform suspend and resume operations perfectly.

It appears like a graphics driver problem.

You can file a bug report or wait till subsequent updates to the driver fixes this.

Comment: is there a bug file report so i can send it to ubuntu developer?
and how to report a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to both our BIOS and Kernel version.  Normally a combo of Lenovo BIOS version older than 2014 and Linux kernel above 3.16 breaks suspend. There is a bug open on it: [bug 1528735](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1528735)